# C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required

Tags: c#

I am receiving an error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'x' of ReadingMaterial.By(string). I'm looking for a little guidance as to why there is an error. Is my syntax wrong, or is there something else I'm missing? I have been trying to learn C# by using some online tutorials and trying to change them up a bit.

```
namespace ReadingMaterials
{
    class Presentation
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aForm Form = new aForm(); // available in hardcopy form aForm.availForm
            Online O = new Online(); // amtBlogs, amtBooks
            Book B = new Book(); // hardCover, softCover
            Magazine M = new Magazine(); // numArticles

            O.blog(5); //contains 5 blogs
            O.oBook(3); //contains 3 online books
            O.By("Beck"); //Written by Beck
            O.words(678); //with 678 combined words
            O.pics(1); // with one pic
            Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.By());

            Form.availForm();

            B.hardCover(10); //10 hardcover books
            B.softCover(2); //2 softcover books
            B.By("Bruce"); //Writen by Bruce
            B.words(188264); //words combined
            B.pics(15); //15 pictures
            Form.availForm();

            M.articles(5); //5 articles
            M.By("Manddi"); //Writen by Manddi
            M.words(18064);//combined words
            M.pics(81); //81 pictures
            Form.availForm();
        }
    }
    class ReadingMaterial
    {
        protected int amtWords;
        string author;
        protected int pic;
        public void words(int w)
        {
            amtWords = w;

        }
        public void By(string x)
        {
            author = x;

        }
        public void pics(int pi)
        {
            pic = pi;
        }

    }
    class Online : ReadingMaterial
    {
         int amtBlogs;
         int amtBooks;
        public void blog(int s)
        {
            amtBlogs = s;
        }
        public void oBook(int b)
        {
            amtBooks = b;
        }
    }
    class Book : ReadingMaterial
    {
         int hard;
         int soft;
        public void hardCover(int h)
        {
            hard = h;
        }
        public void softCover(int s)
        {
            soft = s;
        }
    }
    class Magazine:ReadingMaterial
    {
         int numArticles;
        public void articles(int a)
        {
            numArticles = a; 
        }

    }
    interface IPrintable
    {
        void availForm();
    }
    class aForm : IPrintable
    {
        public void availForm ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available in hard copy form!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `By` method like this, with a parameter:

```
public void By(string x)
{
     author = x;
}
```

But you are trying to call it without a parameter:

```
Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.By()); // not passing a parameter to 'By()'
```

If you want to access the `author` value of `ReadingMaterial` here then I would suggest making it a public property rather than a private field:

```
class ReadingMaterial
    {
        protected int amtWords;
        public string Author { get; private set;}
        // skipped

        public void By(string x)
        {
            Author = x;
        }
```

All of which kinds of begs the question - why use methods to set the values at all? Why not just use properties, as suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859012/43846) by @CarlosGarcia?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling By without any parameters in this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.By());
```

You can add a method to get the value instead:

```
class ReadingMaterial
{
    ...
    public string GetBy()
    {
        return author;
    }
    ....
```

}

Anyways, you might want to use properties instead of functions. You can look at the code working in [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HJUqw9)

```
class ReadingMaterial
{
    public string Author {get;set;}
    ...
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ...
     O.Author = "Beck"; //Written by Beck
     ...
     Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.Author);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.By());` is the culprit. `O.By()` expects a string, and the `By()` function sets the author, but doesn't return any string. Since you've set the author using the `By()` function, you can make the `author` a public field, and do `Console.WriteLine("The auther {0} ", O.author);`

Comment: Um, `author` is **not** a public field.